# Redirecting a page Based on URL Value

Tags: php, https

I am trying to redirecting my register page to `https://` based on parse url value.Below is my code

```
$url = $current_url="//".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

if ($query['view']=='register') {
$porthttp = "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: " . $porthttp);
exit();
}
```

But it is giving error '*server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.*'

what's wrong i am doing?

Comment: You don't check any results. What if `parse_url()` returns false? What if `parse_str()` returns false? What does `$porthttp` look like? Anyway, this is a job for the web server, not a PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting on same page which you accessing so it will not work.
I.e http://localhost/demo/test.php?view=register and you are checking condition like if ($query['view']=='register') {} then you are redirecting on same page using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] so it will go to infinite loop.

Comment: how can i avoid this?

Comment: My preferred method for reloading the same page is $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  

header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
die;

Comment: in my case $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); is redirecting to https://index.php/ not to current url

Comment: What is your URL? If same page or same action then why redirecting in same page. Are you using any PHP framework? Please share details